# How to set the ipython working directory?

Tags: ubuntu, jupyter-notebook

Some ipynb files are stored here:

```
/home/jeanpat/Developpements/iPythonNb
```

Starting ipython as follow to specify the path failed:

```
~$ ipython --notebook-dir=/home/jeanpat/Developpements/iPythonNb notebook
```

with the message:

```
[TerminalIPythonApp] Invalid argument: '--notebook-dir=/home/jeanpat/Developpements/iPythonNb'
```

ubuntu 13.10
ipython 0.13.2

Answer (score 1):

The order of your commands just needs switching:

```
~$ ipython notebook --notebook-dir=/home/jeanpat/Developpements/iPythonNb
```

The equivalent works for me (ubuntu 12.04, ipython 1.1.0).

Answer (score 0):

I have to care about the argument order :

```
~$ ipython notebook --notebook-dir=/home/jeanpat/Developpements/iPythonNb
```